# Persist user settings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I need to save the user's data for the first time he opens the app and never show it again.

Let's say I need the user to enter his first name and other data, and save it so the application can use it later. The user enters his first name, and the next time he opens the application, he doesn't get asked to enter his name again. The application just goes to the main screen.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please Don't Capitalize Every Word And Omit Commas It's Not Proper English.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Do you need help saving the first-time info? Or where/how to save it? Are you using a database? And/or where/how to get the information later?

Comment: @minitech if i don't it'll will no let me post it and look at you

Comment: @PaulSasik i mean at the first time the user open the app it ask him for some info then i take those information and save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use application settings. Open your project's properties (My Project in the Solution Explorer), go to the Settings tab, and make a setting. I'll assume you called it `FirstName`. Keep everything else as-is (User Setting, String) and save.

Now you can use this setting just like any other property, except it'll persist between runs. You can find the property in the `My.Settings` class. To set it the first time:

```
My.Settings.FirstName = userFirstName
```

And to use it later, it's just `My.Settings.FirstName`.